# POS of WSJ in CONLL format from penn tree bank

Tags: nlp

I've got the penn tree bank CD. How to convert designated WSJ documents to conll format? Because the original format is in tree structure.
    E.g. The conll shared task 2000: http://www.cnts.ua.ac.be/conll2000/chunking/ is using treebank. How was this format obtained?
    Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps this page can help:
http://nlp.cs.lth.se/software/treebank-converter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the perl script available from the task page:
http://ilk.uvt.nl/team/sabine/homepage/software.html

Comment: Thank you very much, though I have used this http://www.cs.upc.edu/~srlconll/soft.html as advised by my adviser